# The triangle formed by the $x$-axis, the tangent to $y=1/x$ at a 1st-quadrant point, and the line from the origin to that point is isosceles

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

Here is Prob. 45, Sec. 3.2, in the book *Calculus With Analytic Geometry* by George F. Simmons, 2nd edition:

> Let $P$ be a point on the first-quadrant part of the curve $y = 1/x$. Show that the triangle determined by the $x$-axis, the tangent at $P$, and the line from $P$ to the origin is isosceles, and find its area.

My Attempt:

> Let the point $P$ be given by $P = \left( a, \frac{1}{a} \right)$, where $a > 0$.

> Then the line from $P$ to the origin has equation
> $$ y = \frac{ \frac{1}{a} }{a} x = \frac{1}{a^2} x. \tag{1} $$

> The slope of the tangent line to the curve $y = 1/x$ at the point $P$ is
> $$
> \left( \frac{d y}{d x} \right)_{x = a} = -\frac{1}{a^2},
> $$
> and thus the equation of the tangent line is
> $$
> y = -\frac{1}{a^2} (x-a) + \frac{1}{a} = -\frac{1}{a^2} x + \frac{2}{a}. \tag{2} 
> $$
> And, this line intersects the $x$-axis at the point $(x, 0)$, where
> $$
>  -\frac{1}{a^2} x + \frac{2}{a} = 0,
> $$
> that is,
> $$
> x = \frac{ \frac{2}{a} }{ \frac{1}{a^2} } = 2a.
> $$
> Thus the tangent line to the curve at the point $(a, 1/a)$ intersects the $x$-axis at the point $A$ given by
> $$A = (2a, 0). $$

> And, the point of intersection of the tangent line to the curve at point $P$ and the line from $P$ to the origin is of course the point $P = (a, 1/a)$ itself.

> Thus the three vertices of our triangle are $O = (0, 0)$, $A = (2a, 0)$, and $P = (a, 1/a)$, where $a > 0$. So the sides of our triangle have lengths
> $$
> \left| \overline{OA} \right| = 2a,
> $$
> $$
> \left| \overline{AP} \right| = \sqrt{ (2a-a)^2 + (0-1/a)^2 } = \sqrt{ a^2 + 1/a^2},
> $$
> and
> $$
> \left| \overline{PO} \right| = \sqrt{ (a-0)^2 + (1/a-0)^2 } = \sqrt{a^2 + 1/a^2}.
> $$
> Thus the sides $AP$ and $PO$ are congruent, showing that our triangle is indeed isosceles.

> Finally, since the base of our triangle is the side $OA$ and the altitude is the vertical line segment from the $x$-axis to the point $P$, therefore the area of our triangle is
> $$
> \frac{1}{2} \times (2a) \times \frac{1}{a} = 1.
> $$

Is what I have done correct and clear in each and every detail? Or, are there any issues of accuracy or clarity?

Comment: You don't need to calculate the line OP.  Also, it is much quicker to note that the slope of OP is the same as the tangent at $P$ to the hyperbola except with the sign, so the triangle has equal base angles and hence is isoceles with area (half base)*(height)=1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me.  A geometric perspective to consider:

When we find point $A =(2a, 0)$, notice that $P$ is directly above the midpoint $OA$. (This midpoint is $C = (a, 0)$.)

The triangles $OCP$ and $ACP$ are congruent, right-angled triangles that are mirror images of each other ($CP$ as a common edge).

Hence $OPA$ is an isosceles triangle.

Moreover if we rotate $ACP$ around $P$ until it forms a rectangle with $OCP$ (which occurs when $A$ moves to $O$), we get a rectangle with base $a$ and height $1/a$ hence it has area $1$.